# Python object1 = object2

Tags: python, class, variables, object

I am writing a vector class in python (just to see if i can). i ran into a problem with the subtract method and i have no idea what could be causing this.
this is the class (i omitted "class Vector:").

```
def __init__(self, p):
    print self
    self.p = p

def __str__(self):
    return str(list(self.p))

def equals(self, v):
    if type(self) == type(v):
        return str(self) == str(v)
    return false

def size(self):
    return len(self.p)

def add(self, v):
    a = self.p
    b = v.p
    if self.size() == v.size():
        for i in range(0, self.size()):
            a[i] += b[i]
        return Vector(a)
    raise Exception()


def subtract(self, v):
    a = self.p
    b = v.p
    if self.size() == v.size():
        for i in range(0, self.size()):
            a[i] -= b[i]
        return Vector(a)
    raise Exception()

def dot(self, v):
    total = 0
    if self.size() == v.size():
        for i in range(0, len(self.p)):
            total += self.p[i] * v.p[i]
        return total
    raise Exception()

def norm(self):
    total = 1
    if self.size() == v.size():
        for i in range(0, len(self.p)):
            total += self.p[i]^2
        return total
    raise Exception()
```

when i try to do:

```
a = Vector([1,1])
a.subtract(Vector[1,1])
print a
```

my thought says i should get [1,1] as output because i do not change any values of Vector a when i do the subtraction, i return a new vector with the values it should have. when i print the object it shows me that it is in a different space in memory but my output from 'print a' is [0,0]

also if i do

```
a = Vector(1,1)
b = a
a.subtract(Vector([1,1])
print a,b
```

my output is [0,0][0,0], what i want is [0,0][1,1]
why does b change with a ?

Comment: aren't there methods like `__sub__` and `__add__` in python?

Comment: See this [code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d63da5f36c94605e285), I wort it to review vectors, you way find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

```
(1, 1) - (1, 1) == (0, 0)
```

The output of your program is correct. You change the values of `a` in your function with `a[i] -= b[i]` where `a` is the list of coordinates (**not** a copy of the list) in `self` and `b` the list of coordinates (again, **not** a copy) in `v`.

Second question:

```
b = a
```

`a` and `b` are now the **same** object (not different objects with the same value), so they change simultaneously.

Think of `a` and `b` as addresses for your computer.

```
a = Vector(1,1)           # There is a Vector object somewhere in memory, e.g. 12345. Then a = 12345
b = a                     # b = a = 12345 (still the address of the same Vector object)
a.subtract(Vector([1,1])) # Change whatever is stored at the address of a = 12345
print a,b                 # both are still the address of the same object you modified in the previous step!
```

Comment: my output of print a should be (1,1) because i return a new vector with coords a.p. what about when i said b = Vector(a.p)?
shouldnt i get a new vector with the same coordinates?